# Chrome API in React functional component not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app

I am trying to make a chrome extension and would love to use React, but after a full week of running into dead ends this seems to not be the ideal route. Thus, I decided to ask for a few suggestions here from you fine SO users as a last ditch effort before simply using Vanilla JS.

Here is my `public/manifest.json` file (I manually change "js":[] field to match the build folder's name for now):

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "0.1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["/static/js/main.356978b8.chunk.js"]
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/"],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Title"
  }
}
```

My thinking is that the content script would be all the React function component files and the overall `index.js` using the above.

Here is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "env": {
      "webextensions": true
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image: Folder Structure]

**src folder**:

```
// src/App.js
function App() {
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log(request.tabs);
});

export default App;

// src/index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**public folder**:

```
// public/background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.tabs.create(
    {
      windowId: null,
      url: "http://localhost:3000",
      active: true,
      openerTabId: tab.id,
    },
    (newTab) => {

      // wait for tab to load, then send message with tabs
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo) => {
        if (changeInfo.status == "complete" && tabId == newTab.id) {
          chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, (tabs) => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(newTab.id, { tabs });
          });
        }
      });
    }
  );
});

// public/index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `background.js` simply opens a new tab to `http://localhost:3000` when the extension button is clicked with `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab)=>{...})`. **This works fine**.

Adding the `build` folder to `Load Unpacked` in Chrome Extensions produces the extension, but when I click on the button and the new tab is created, I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined
```

I know that `npm run eject` can be used to automate/set the filename in `/static/js/...`, but for now I am fine with simply changing it on every build change.

Any clues or ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. Please also share any code/file content/error messages/etc... as formatted code snippets versus images.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for the comment. I updated the description as per your request, please kindly remove the "close" vote if it was yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your extension uses ***two*** copies of the same React app JS file (`"static/js/main.*.chunk.js"`) that run in different contexts. One copy runs as a content script injected into active page and this one should run without errors. But there is also another copy that runs within CRA's dev server (`localhost:3000`) you open in a new tab. And this one runs as *ordinary* JS file without any connection to your extension, so it ***cannot*** call Chrome API. That's why you get that error.

A possible solution would be to split that JS file into two separate parts: one (ordinary JS related to `index.html`) - to do React rendering only, another (content script) - to listen messages from extension. [Communication](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#host-page-communication) between such two parts can be done using [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). In your case something like below:

public/manifest.json:

```
{
...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
...
}
```

public/contentScript.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  window.postMessage({ type: "FROM_EXT", tabs: request.tabs }, "http://localhost:3000");
});
```

src/index.js:

```
...
window.addEventListener("message", event => {
  if (event.source != window)
    return;
  const {type, tabs} = event.data;
  if (type !== "FROM_EXT")
    return;
  console.log(tabs);
});
```

Furthermore I'd suggest you to use custom CRA template - [`complex-browserext`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-template-complex-browserext) (plug). It facilitates usage of Create React App with browser extensions. Also see [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-build-a-rich-chrome-extension-quickly-with-create-react-app-and-redux-d9b64cf64832) for particular usage example (another plug).

Comment: First off all thank you for the detailed response. I attempted splitting the JS file as you mentioned but could not get it to work. Is there a chance that you could provide a basic example of this file?

Comment: Note that you cannot load/open localhost URL in production. You have to change your background script to open page within extension (using [runtime.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL)).

Comment: Again thank you for the useful information. Not sure why you deleted my previous comment though.

Comment: @lbragile I didn't delete your comments